# where and while loop not seem to be working

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select some values using 'where' and 'and' clause in bootstrap. The code selects only one value meanwhile there are more than one in the database. Here goes the code:

```
<ul class="collapsible collapsible-accordion">
                      <li><a class="collapsible-header waves-effect arrow-r"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>ENGLISH LANGUAGE<i class="fa fa-angle-down rotate-icon"></i></a>
                    <?php
                            $sql = "SELECT note_id, class, subject, topic, content, author FROM notes  WHERE subject = 'ENGLISH LANGUAGE' AND class = 'JHS 2'";
                            $result = $pdo->query($sql);
                            $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                            while($row=$result->fetch()){

                                ?>

                        <div class="collapsible-body">
                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                <?php echo '<li>'?><a data-id="<?php echo $key['note_id']?>" href="<?php echo $key['note_id']?>" class="waves-effect" id="getUser"><?php echo $key['topic']?></a>
                                <?php echo '</li>';?>
                                <li><a href="#" class="waves-effect">Registration form</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <?php


                            }



                    ?>
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch multiple records in a loop, you should use method `::fetch_row()`  ([PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php)).

So your code should look like this:

```
                <ul class="collapsible collapsible-accordion">
                      <li><a class="collapsible-header waves-effect arrow-r"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>ENGLISH LANGUAGE<i class="fa fa-angle-down rotate-icon"></i></a>
                    <?php
                            $sql = "SELECT note_id, class, subject, topic, content, author FROM notes  WHERE subject = 'ENGLISH LANGUAGE' AND class = 'JHS 2'";
                            $result = $pdo->query($sql);
                            $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                            while($row=$result->fetch_row()){

                                ?>

                        <div class="collapsible-body">
                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                <?php echo '<li>'?><a data-id="<?php echo $key['note_id']?>" href="<?php echo $key['note_id']?>" class="waves-effect" id="getUser"><?php echo $key['topic']?></a>
                                <?php echo '</li>';?>
                                <li><a href="#" class="waves-effect">Registration form</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                            }
                    ?>
                </ul>
```

By using `::fetch()` method, you are fetching whole results array/object.

Comment: fetch_row makes the code not render in the browser at all

Comment: Is the error displayed instead? Or is it blank page? Can you post an apache/php error log here then?